# flashdevelop is not finding my png file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am trying to load my png file to my application. here is the code

```
var map:mapLoader = new mapLoader();
map.loadMap("tile.png");
```

Then here is my file that loads it. it throws the error right when it gets to

```
loader.load(new URLRequest(currentMap));
```

if I comment it out. then the error goes away. below is the code in its entirety

```
package {
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;    

    public class mapLoader extends Sprite{

        private var currentMap:String;
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var worldRows:Number = 100;
        private var worldCols:Number = 100;
        public var world:Array;
        public var mapTile:BitmapData;
        public var arry:Array = new Array();

        public function mapLoader():void
        {
            // the output window width and height in pixels

            worldCols=100;      
            worldRows=100;          


            world = new Array();
        }

        public function loadMap(mapName:String = "empty"):void
        {
            currentMap = mapName;

            if(currentMap != "empty")
            {
                //load in tile sheet image
                loader = new Loader();
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,tilesLoadInit);
                loader.load(new URLRequest(currentMap));
            }
        }//End MapLoader

         private function tilesLoadInit (e:Event):void {
               mapTile = Bitmap(loader.content).bitmapData;

         }
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

Comment: You should provide the specific error being thrown.

Comment: I just tested your code, which looked fine, and it is in fact working as expected.  What error are you seeing?  Have you run this in debug mode to find a specific line number?  

Does you INIT event handler ever get called?

Answer (score 2):

The code is loading an external (ie. not embedded) asset, "tile.png", which should be placed near your HTML page or SWF file depending on how you play it.

As a rule, the path of these external elements is relative to the "top level container":

- the HTML page if you're doing a website,
- the SWF file itself if you are playing it standalone (as an EXE or when you run the project from FlashDevelop).

This is something to be very careful about and a source of confusion for beginners.